# Splitting attribute using Python Parser in ModelBuilder expression?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, field-calculator, python-parser

Goal: I need to upgrade an existing ModelBuilder where the expressions use Python 9.3.

Work process & Goal:
My *.mxd Have 1 attribute field containing the following build: X1-X2-X3-x4_x5_x6-x7.
Example: G-OI-KI-VUUR_NAAMGEVING_0000101111_VECT_12X001111-X. I tryed to split is on the ‘-’ and ‘_’ signs because the names have a different length.

My goal is putting the fields X1 - X7 in separate text-fields by using a ModelBuilder which is coded with Python 9.3.

**Issue**: one of those 'transformations' (X4) isn’t working properly. 
I used *|  **!LAYER!.split("-")[3]**   |*  A new field is created, but I got as a result: x4_x5_x6-x7.  I only wanted x4.

Matthieu Brbt came with a solution to use:

```
(!LAYER!.split("-")[-1]).split("_")[0]
```

instead. Unfortunately this ended up with an error: 000539: Indentation Error: unexpected indent (, line 1) Failed to execute (Calculate Field)  Matthieu suggested to check for empty spaces in the expression but those were not here.

This is what my expression looks like:

[image]

**How can I make a split based on the ‘-’ and ‘_’  for  field x4 ?**

Comment: here you divide Type by name (two strings). I don't understand what you want to do with this ratio. Could you give an example of input and output ?

Comment: Radouxju, thank you for your reaction. The information is shown in my question is 1 field(string) containing the following build: X1-X2-X3-x4_x5_x6_x7. What I tried to do is place X4 in a seperate field (text) by using a modelbuilder. In this modelbuilder I (try to) say: create a new field then,  make a split, so only X4 is placed in a new field. In the current state the expression only make a split between x3 and x4 but not between x4 and x5. So the new field contains  X4_X5_X6_X7. Some how I can not make a second split on "_" (between X4 and X5).

Comment: i did use the python expression: !LAYER!.split("-")[3] / !LAYER!.split("_")[1]. Can u show me that is wrong?

Comment: @matthieu Brbt's answer seems correct : splitting the result of your first split. (first split ).split()

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a Calculate Field tool or somewhere else?

Comment: You are trying to divide x4/x6?

Comment: i updated my question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show the *type-field* you can try with this :

```
 (!LAYER!.split("-")[-1]).split("_")[0]
```

Comment: Matthieu, thank you: i tried your code ( (!LAYER!.split("-")[-1]).split("_")[0]) but I got the following ERROR 000539: IndentationError: unexpected indent (<expression>, line 1)
Failed to execute (Calculate Field).  I also tried the combination.  My build: X1-X2-X3-x4_x5_x6_x7 so I also tried (!LAYER!.split("-")[3]).split("_")[1] but no succes :S

Comment: Checks if'there space after or before the python expression. And i think that the correct code is  `(!LAYER!.split("-"))[-1]).split("_")[0]`

Comment: i tried it with and widhout spaces. unfortiantly widhout succes.  Now I am wondering how i can give you more information to solve this problem.  Shall i post an example or is not the purpose of this site?

Comment: @MbZ To provide additional details just click on the edit button beneath your Question to revise it.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: A bracket is missing in your Expression Screenshot. For the example  "G-OI-KI-VUUR_NAAMGEVING_0000101111_VECT_12X001111-X" if you want the string "VUUR"  the code is `!LAYER!.split("-")[3].split("_")[0]`. In the Expression Screenshot the fields names are with quote, try to add quotes or double clik on the name field to add in the expression to be sure you have the correct field name.